# Why are other sites ranking for our content?

Tags: seo, google-search

I co-run a job board, and part of our service is to post jobs that people post with us on multiple boards. The content originates with us, and we are basically the god version, any updates made on our site by our clients gets pushed out to the other job boards.

The problem is, when you search in Google for the specific job by its title, we are nowhere to be found. Instead the other job boards that we publish the job to come up as search results.

I have added a tag for

`<link rel="publisher" href="https://plus.google.com/117671874862128537527"/>`

to try and tell Google that we are the owner of the content, which looks to appear correctly using their [snippet tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.salonstaff.com.au%2Fjob%2Fqualified-hairdresser-for-salon-hairhouse-warehouse-church-st-brighton%2Fin%2Fmelbourne%2F14924), but we still are nowhere when it comes to searching Google for our content.

Any ideas?

A running example:

`QUALIFIED HAIRDRESSER FOR SALON - HAIRHOUSE WAREHOUSE CHURCH ST, BRIGHTON`

The content on our site: [here](http://www.salonstaff.com.au/job/qualified-hairdresser-for-salon-hairhouse-warehouse-church-st-brighton/in/melbourne/14924)

Google search for the job title: [here](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=QUALIFIED+HAIRDRESSER+FOR+SALON+-+HAIRHOUSE+WAREHOUSE+CHURCH+ST%2C+BRIGHTON&oq=QUALIFIED+HAIRDRESSER+FOR+SALON+-+HAIRHOUSE+WAREHOUSE+CHURCH+ST%2C+BRIGHTON&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j69i62l2.215j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&ei=TJERUruTOuaQiAfxuYCICQ&fp=bf71f573e477f022&q=QUALIFIED+HAIRDRESSER+FOR+SALON+-+HAIRHOUSE+WAREHOUSE+CHURCH+ST,+BRIGHTON&sa=N&start=20)

It's extremely frustrating since we are driving traffic to other sites for our own content.

Comment: If you type `site:your_url`, you can see that your content is not indexed in google search engine. Read about [search operators](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/136861?hl=en).

Comment: This is incorrect, it is indexed.

Comment: I see that _this page_ now ranks at #4 for that text!! (And I can see you double posted on StackOverflow at #7 - mods will migrate questions from one site to another, you shouldn't do it yourself and double post.)

Comment: Rather confusingly, one of the results (at #2) is for careerjet.co.uk and is naturally listed under "jobs in the United Kingdom" - this job is clearly not for the UK!? However, this does link back to your site (in Australia).

Comment: thanks w3d, didn't know mods could / would migrate posts over. I saw too that this page ranked above us... frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

`link rel="publisher"` is not for telling search engines you are the original source of syndicated content. It's just to link up your companies Google + page in the search results, so you can see an image and brand name.

The correct way to tell search engines you are the original source of syndicated is using a [cross domain canonical tag](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.au/2009/12/handling-legitimate-cross-domain.html). This where a canonical tag is set on pages on these other domains referencing the original page. However this is rather difficutl to set up, as of course you don't control these other domains.

Google is normally quite Good at figuring out who is the original source of content, but with syndicated content if often gets it wrong. One of the problems I see here is some of the websites with the content are very well known, authoritative type sites, such as careerjet.com.au.

The only real solution in these situations is simply to have two sets of content. One set you syndicate out, then a 2nd set which you publish on your website. This way you have original, unique content on your site and you aren't leaving any thing up to chance.

Comment: Thanks, I've since added in a `link rel="author"` tag, and already have a canonical tag for ourselves as there's two ways of seeing the content on our site, however like you say hinted, it's near impossible to get other sites to have a canonical link to us. I thought the same thing with the separate versions of content, but wanted to avoid that as much as possible, as it's our clients content, not ours. So could be tricky to edit without direct permission.

Answer (score 0):

Its just because of domain authority.

Your website seems to have less authority and trust in eyes of Google as compare to rest of the websites. When google find relevant content it ranks website as per the number of links that domain / URL has. Those links define the authority of website and trust of Google in a website.

All you have to do it to give links to your website. Raise the authority of the website an a time will come when you will se your post ranking higher in search results.

However to get quick results here is the tip

Give some links to particular job post page
And use all keywords but make content unique